# return form result laravel don't show

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried tons of hours now. Bu still cannot figure it out. 
So, I want to return the form input on same page after submit, via the controller.

But it don't give me anything. If I only using `return Input::get('email');` then it at least show the result in a white page.

Any idea how to proceed?
My codes looks like:

Controller:

```
class SuperController extends BaseController   {
    public function quote() {
       if (Input::get('email') == "") {
        return array('empty' => true);
       } else {
        return View::make('users',array(Input::get()));
       }
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('users', 'SuperController@quote');
```

Users file:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('form')
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'SuperController@quote')) }}
        <!-- Email -->
        {{ Form::token() }}
        {{ Form::text('email'); }}
        {{ Form::submit('LCLCL'); }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset` and `with()`

```
class SuperController extends BaseController   {
    public function quote() {
       if (isset(Input::get('email'))) {
        return array('empty' => true);
       } else {
        return View::make('users')->with('input', Input::get());
       }
    }
}
```

And a *HTTP GET* route

```
Route::get('users', 'SuperController@quote');
```